# Designation & Convenience Initializer

Tags: ios, swift

I  have a query regarding initializer in swift. As per Apples' [Swift3.0](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID203)

1. A designated initializer must call a designated initializer from its immediate superclass.
2. A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class.
3. A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated initializer.

Now I have two class A & B (subclass of A). A & B both have two designated initializer with below structure

[image]

Can anyone suggest how class B's designated initializer will call to class A's initializers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two designated initializers in `A`, these are non-ambiguous due to different signatures, and can be differentiated from each other. This means you can readily call the appropriate *designated* initializer of `A` from the subclass `B`. E.g., for `A` as

```
class A {
    var a: Int

    // designated "#1"
    init() {
        a = 0
    }

    // designated "#2"
    init(_ a: Int) {
        self.a = a
    }

    // convenience initializer for A
    convenience init(_ foo: String) {
        print(foo)
        self.init(42)
    }
}
```

We have, e.g.

```
class B: A {
    let b: Int

    // designated "sub#1"
    override init() {
        b = 42
        super.init() // use A's designated #1
    }

    // designated "sub#2"
    override init(_ a: Int) {
        b = 24
        super.init(a) // use A's designated #2
    }

    // non-overriding designated "#3"
    init(b: Int) {
        self.b = b
        super.init() // use A's designated #1
    }

    // convenience initializer for B
    convenience init(_ foo: String) {
        print(foo)
        self.init() // use B's designated #1
    }
        // you may only call designated initializers of the superclass
}
```

Note however that the initializers of a subclass may *only call designated initializers of its superclass*. This is covered by rules 1 and 2 in [the Language Guide - Initializers - Initializer Delegation for Class Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) [**emphasis** mine]:

> #### Initializer Delegation for Class Types
>
> To simplify the relationships between designated and convenience
>   initializers, Swift applies the following three rules for delegation
>   calls between initializers:
>
> ***Rule 1***
>
> A designated initializer **must call a designated initializer from its
>   immediate superclass**.
>
> ***Rule 2***
>
> A convenience initializer **must call another initializer from the same
>   class**.
>
> ***Rule 3***
>
> A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.

So you may not access the convenience initializers of `A` from the convenience initializers of `B`, and the designated initializers of `B` must naturally, by rule 1 above, call only the designated initializers of `A`.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  In DOC, Apple  says 'Both designated initializers must call the single designated initializer from the superclass'. So in above case which initializer of 'A' would get the call?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS in the example in the language guide, `A` has only a single designated initializer, therefor the two designated initializers of `B` have no choice in which designated initializer of its superclass they must call, since there is only one. _If_, on the other hand, the superclass has several designated initializers, the designated initializers of the (immediate) subclass may naturally choose any of these two call. Recall that a designated initializer fully initializes the class (_"A designated initializer fully initializes all properties introduced by that class ..."_).

Comment: ... which means, in the example above, that out of the two designated initializers of `A`, the one that gets the call from a given designated initializer in `B` is the one with a matching signature to the call from `B`. Since we have two designated initializers in `A`, we know that these _must have different signatures_ (and can hence be differentiated), or we would have ambiguity and be prompted with a compiler error.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS happy to help :)